# How do I show a table inside a CTabItem using the SWT

Tags: java, swt, ctabitem

This is probably a trivial question for most but here goes...

I am using SWT and want to show a table inside a CTabItem (or a TabItem if it's easier).
I tried to create the table and use the CTabItem as the parent when doing so, however it doesnt accept this as a parameter (asking me to change CTabItem to Composite).

I figured there must be a way of showing a table inside a tab, I'm just not sure how to do it, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `(C)TabFolder` as parent instead. And on the `(C)TabItem` you have to call `tabItem.setControl(yourTable)`.

Answer (score 1):

Howto put controls onto a tab see this [snippet](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/Createsatabbeddisplaywithfourtabsandafewcontrols.htm), use this as base and modify and replace a control with your table.